# MVVM validation and user feedback with DTOs

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, cqrs

Currently we are doing CQRS without Event Sourcing.

We have commands (e.g. UpdateUser) and queries (e.g.: GetUser, GetAllUsers).

Our domain is only known on the server because there are multiple different clients. Clients receive their data via DTOs, they don't know about the actual entities on the server.

Currently if we have a View and ViewModel where we want to represent the UserDTO and validate it, we map the UserDTO to an UserDTOValidation object where there are some methods "IsValid()..." etc...

Now this works but takes a lot of time and mapping and will be hard to manage in large solutions.
e.g.:

1. we query GetUser
2. the server maps the UserEntity to UserDTO
3. we receive a UserDTO
4. we map the UserDTO to a UserDTOValidation object (kind of wrapper)
5. check if it is valid UserDTOValidation.IsValid()
6. send UpdateUserCommand with UserDTO (which is stored in UserDTOValidation)
7. UserDTO is received on server and has extra validation (e.g. to see if it is unique, no duplicate data etc...)
8. In case UserDTO is not valid the UpdateUserCommand has return value e.g. -1.

This validation feels wrong, but it works.

Can anybody show a better way of working (code samples if possible) that does validation of the user input + gives feedback and has validation on client and server.

Keep in mind that we are working with DTOs, entities from the server are not known on the clients, only DTOs.

**Update:**

the UserDTOValidation also has "IsDirty" property to known if it has been edited, because we don't want to send update commands on that that has not been changed. I don't think it would be ok to add IsDirty property and validation to a DTO itself. So this is an additional problem that I don't know how to improve.

Answer (score 1):

> the server maps the UserEntity to UserDTO

If you're applying CQRS you don't need to perform this mapping. The read side already have a UserDTO projection ready.

> send UpdateUserCommand with UserDTO (which is stored in
>   UserDTOValidation)

You shouldn't be sending the UserDTO as a command parameter. You should only provide to the command the minimum possible data it needs for executing.

Also  if you have an UpdateUserCommand you should rethink whether you need to use CQRS, I'm guessing CRUD would fit your problem in a much simpler way.

> UserDTO is received on server and has extra validation (e.g. to see if
>   it is unique, no duplicate data etc...)

Although you can prevalidate the uniqueness on the client side against a read side query and in 99,9999% per cent of the cases it would be enough, there are situations where the command will fail at the domain level.

On this cases you will have to deal with it the way your're doing, i.e. waiting for a return value or possibly catching an exception.